# std::move, std::forward, value type and template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Let say I have this code

```
template <typename T> void Swap(T&& a, T&& b) {
    T tmp = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
}
```

According to my understanding of [this talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11), when calling `Swap(a, b)`, the compiler should deduce the fact that `T&&` should be `T&` and convert it. But in this case GCC gives me the following error :

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'std::remove_reference<int&>::type {aka int}' 
T tmp = std::move(a);
```

I either have to call `Swap` using `Swap(std::forward<int>(a), std::forward<int>(b))` or `Swap(std::move(a), std::move(b))`, or to replace the `Swap` signature by `Swap(T& a, T& b)`.

Why is that the case ? What is the correct usage here ?

Comment: "*the compiler should deduce the fact that `T&&` should be `T&`*" Er, right, so that makes the first line `T& tmp = std::move(a);` which is nonsensical, as you can't bind an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference. You seem to know this, so I don't understand what your actual question is...

Comment: Swapping two rvalues is perhaps a bit silly: `Swap(1 + 2, 2 + 1)`...? Something like `std::exchange` may have slightly more value.

Comment: @ildjarn: In my experience, people sometimes experience a "blind zone" in their thinking. Like the blind zone in the middle of your field of vision, you don't notice it at all unless you force your visual subsystem to generate e.g. a floating sausage (some children delight in this, when taught how to do it). My most common blind zone is the binary switch. Maybe it's the same mechanism that supports religious belief. Anyway it's common.

Comment: @ildjarn I was thinking the compiler replaces this call to `Swap(int&, int&)` (hence leading to `T == int`) not by `Swap(int& &&, int& &&)` and then `T` which leads to `T` being `int&`. In this case the error makes perfect sense.

Comment: @KerrekSB That was just the first example that came to my mind when trying this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this:

```
template <typename T> void Swap(T&& a, T&& b)
{
    using U = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;

    U tmp = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

As you hinted at in your question, in your example, `T` is deduced as `int&`, and the initialization `int& tmp = std::move(a);` is ill-formed.

Comment: Beat me to it.. :(